# Is it possible to extract only tables from pdf using camelot? It should detect only tables not text

Tags: python, tabula, python-camelot

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('test1.pdf', flavor='stream',edge_tol=500, row_tol=10, pages='all', split_text=True, flag_size=True)

camelot.plot(table, kind='contour')

table.to_csv('result'+str(i)+'.csv',index=False)
```

Currently I use this logic but it fetches everything with text theory.

Comment: With flavor='stream', there is this problem.
Did you try with flavor='lattice'?

Comment: Thanks @Anakin87 but I have multi pages PDF with border less tables including other text paragraphs. Please suggest.

Comment: Any news on a solution for this ? I have the same issue

Comment: Yes, Sorry for late update, I processed data once I fetched table text from pdf. My conclusion after evaluated possible OCR libraries  is none of them give ready accurate results without pre or post processing.  Able2Extract tool is one of the solution to get major score of accuracy.